# Contradiction in the Varāha purana?

Tags: puranas, shaiva-siddhanta, rudra, pashupata-shaivism, varaha-purana

In the Varāha purana, Rudra Geeta, Lord Rudra says -

> It is for the delusion of those who are outside the Vedic  fold that I
> introduced the sàstra called Naya, Siddhànta etc.

~Varāha Purana 70.41

From the Above, It is inferred that Naya and Siddhanta philosophies of Shaivism are termed as Avaidika and delusory as per the purāna .

But in the Very next chapter, Nissvāsasamhitā, A Shaiva Sāstra that literally deals with Naya and Siddhantika teachings is being called Veda-sammata!

> Requested by them thus, I produced a Samhita which  contained rules
> for Vedic rites as well.
>
> This Samhita was named Nissvasa, and Babhravya and  Sandila were
> absorbed in it.
>
> Deluded by me, people out of selfish motives, will pro-  mulgate their
> own sAstras in Kaliyuga.
>
> **The Nissvāsasamhitā with a lakh of verses alone is authoritative and
> that gives the discipline regarding Pasupata.  This follows the path
> of the Vedas, and whatever is  Outside its scope should be considered
> as impure.**

~ Varāha purana 71.53-57

Now the question is, why is a Naya/Siddhantika text being called  Veda-sammata, when the philosophy itself is said to be avaidika and stated to be created for delusion?

How can a certain Scripture follow the Path of the Vedas and be deluding at the same time?

How can this contradiction be explained?

Comment: How do you know that the nissvasasamhita deals with Nyaya and Siddhantika teachings? What is the reference?

Comment: @AmritenduMukhopadhyay It's 'Naya' not Nyāya to be specific. You can refer to the following paper for a view of its contents.  https://www.academia.edu/12975138/The_Ni%C5%9Bv%C4%81satattvasa%E1%B9%83hit%C4%81_The_Earliest_Surviving_%C5%9Aaiva_Tantra_Volume_1_A_Critical_Edition_and_Annotated_Translation_of_the_M%C5%ABlas%C5%ABtra_Uttaras%C5%ABtra_and_Nayas%C5%ABtra_Ed_GOODALL_in_collaboration_with_Alexis_SANDERSON_and_Harunaga_ISAACSON_with_contributions_of_Nirajan_KAFLE_Diwakar_ACHARYA_and_others

Comment: thanks for the link.